# Check the type of a property in neomodel

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, neomodel

Is it possible to get the type of a property in neomodel?
For example something like this:

```
for n in MyNodeModel.properties: 
    if n == StructuredNode:
        print('StructuredNode')
```

I hope my questions is clear...

Comment: Well if `n` is a property, why can't you just use `type(n)`?   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: That's the point. I want something like .properties so I can use type or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you just need to get the property object from the model:

```
if isinstance(MyNodeModel.your_property, StringProperty):
    print("a string")
```

If this doesn't answer your question please open an issue on github